# Is it bad practice to parse inside an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Lets say for arguments sake that I'm not using closures and I don't need to use this function more than once.

```
    var xhr = null;

    function quote() {
        try {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        if (xhr == null) {
            alert("Ajax not supported by your browser!");
            return;
        }
        var url = "data.php";
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200)) {
                    var doc =  xhr.responseText;
                    //Parse doc here ?
                    //Or
                    //return doc; ?
                }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
```

Passing `doc` to a dedicated function for parsing seems unnecessary, but I feel guilty parsing inside the ajax call, as if it's a poor design decision.

Is there a right way to go about this?

Comment: *"Lets say for arguments sake that I'm not using closures..."* Yes, you are (two of them, in that code).

Comment: I meant using the whole function as a closure. Either way, I probably need to read further on this subject as I still don't understand it fully. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @ LifeQuery: FWIW, I've written a blog post on the subject: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an opinion-based question, but I don't see any problem with parsing it there other than the general "keep functions short, and have them do one thing" guideline that you appear to be familiar with already (hence your sense of unease). Unless the parsing is large, it doesn't seem like it would bloat the function much, and one could take the view that the function's one purpose is to retrieve the parsed document. If the parsing is more than a couple of lines, then I'd keep it separate. And of course, keeping it separate makes it separately testable, which is also useful.

But (unrelated) I would certainly move the `xhr` variable *into* the `quote` function, if that's the only place it's used. Also, there's no way for `xhr` to be `null` at the point you check it (if the browser doesn't have either `XMLHttpRequest` or `ActiveXObject`, that code throws before the line doing the check).